# cannot assign newly created linked list to another variable

Tags: c, linked-list

I have following code:

```
Price *ptr=NULL;

Price *ptr1 = ptr;

ptr_file =fopen(pvalue,"r");
if (!ptr_file)
    exit(1);

while ((c=fgetc(ptr_file))!=EOF)
{       
    if(c==',' && flag==2)
    {
        temp_price[i] = '\0';
        i = 0;
        flag = 0;
        ptr->Price = atoi(temp_price);
        ptr->sold_cpy=0;
    }

    if(flag == 2)
        temp_price[i++]=c;  

    if(c==',' && flag == 1)
    {
       ptr->BookId[i++]='\0';
       i=0;
       flag=2;
    }
    if(!fflag)
    {
        ptr = (Price*) malloc (sizeof(Price));
        if (ptr==NULL) 
           exit (1);  
        flag=1;
        fflag=1;
    }

    if(flag == 1)
        ptr->BookId[i++] = c;

    if(c=='\n')
    {
       ptr = ptr->Next_Price;

       ptr = (Price*) malloc (sizeof(Price));
       if (ptr==NULL) 
           exit (1);    
        flag =1;               
    }   
}
ptr->Next_Price = NULL;
fclose(ptr_file);

for(ptr = ptr1;ptr!=NULL;ptr=ptr->Next_Price)   
    printf("%s %d %d\n",ptr->BookId,ptr->Price,ptr->sold_cpy);
```

The problem is the values are correctly assigned to ptr but not to ptr1. I have already pointed the beginning of the node with ptr1:

```
Price *ptr1 = ptr;
```

Here is the struct definition:

```
typedef struct Price_ Price;
struct Price_{
char   BookId[20];
int    Price;
int    sold_cpy;
Price * Next_Price;
};
```

I am toatally fed up with what went wrong..any idea??

Comment: How do you know it's not correctly assigned?

Comment: use a debugger or add trace messages.

Comment: You don't link the new nodes into the list, and you have memory leaks as you overwrite the pointers.

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't created a linked list, many problems in the code:

Just take this one:

You retrieve here the pointer for the next link, which was never set, contains garbage:

```
ptr = ptr->Next_Price;
```

Here you discard that value, allocate space for the next node, but you never store it as a link in the previous node:

```
ptr = (Price*) malloc (sizeof(Price));
```

Switch the order:

```
ptr->Next_Price = (Price*) malloc (sizeof(Price));
ptr = ptr->Next_Price;
```

Another problem right at the beginng: You try to store the head node (`Price *ptr1 = ptr;`), but at that point `ptr` is NULL.

Pick a debugger, and go through your program step-by-step. At some point in the future you should be able to do the same thing in your head (or with paper&pencil) but looks like at the moment you're struggling with some basic concepts... so the best way to compare reality with what you *think* your program does is to run it in a debugger.

Comment: yes, was just updating.. I guess there are more problems, but let's leave the rest for him as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks, got it working now..one problem you already mentioned above.. secondly, for assignment of ptr to ptr1 I need to assign it after first malloc. This is a very small part of very long assignment..working for hours made my mind so blank that I forgot a basic concept that Malloc returns a new address.. anyhow, thanks for the help..!!